# Matplotlib animation draw dynamic artists without blit

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw dynamic number of artists in the update function of the animation. Specifically, I wanted to label the peaks of an moving power spectral density plot. There are no guarantee that the number of peaks will be the same, thus I can't use text.set_text, here's what I used:

```
def update(i):
    global line, frequency, psdmatrix, text, recordline, ax
    text.set_text('Period ' + str(i))
    line.set_data(frequency, psdmatrix[i])
    maxlist = get_max(psdmatrix[i])
    texts = []
    for each in maxlist:
        freq = frequency[each[0]]
        texts.append(ax.text(freq, each[1]*3, 'Peak %.02f' % freq))
    return line, recordline, texts
```

However, texts don't clear themselves with each iteration, instead they stack on top of each other, with few iterations there are hundreds of texts artists. Is there an efficient way where I could get rid of the texts without getting rid of other more stable elements? I'm on mac so I can't use blit=True. The resulting image is like this:

[All the texts objects are on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM4ex.png)

Thanks!

Comment: If the only problem is to use `blit=True`, I would guess it is working if using a different backend, e.g. `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`. It even seems that the macos backend [should now support animations](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6178).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the old texts from the figure before creating new ones. 
Define `texts` outside the function and iterate over it to remove and delete the old texts. The following should hence work with `blit=False`:

```
texts = []

def update(i):
    global line, frequency, psdmatrix, text, recordline, ax
    text.set_text('Period ' + str(i))
    line.set_data(frequency, psdmatrix[i])
    maxlist = get_max(psdmatrix[i])
    for t in texts:
        t.remove()
        del t
    texts[:] = []
    for each in maxlist:
        freq = frequency[each[0]]
        texts.append(ax.text(freq, each[1]*3, 'Peak %.02f' % freq))
```

*(Note that this is untested because of lack of mcve.)*